# Recover Whatsapp Keyfile

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have a backup of my whatsapp database, however i accidently wiped the keyfile from the system partition when i tried to recover my phone that did not boot any more.

Does anyone know if there is any backup of this file somewhere on the internal storage of even in the cloud at whatsapp, or if it is somehow possible to decrypt the database without the file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to decrypt the database without the keyfile, and WhatsApp make a point of not having your messages in the clear (they are encrypted end to end)

So unfortunately you have no chance of getting your data back without that keyfile.